# Uncaught TypeError: in JS this.changeRoundScore is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.roll (app.js:35)

Tags: javascript

I'm relatively new to JS and I'm getting an error when trying to write a simple 'pig game'. I have tried a variety of things, but I haven't figured out exactly what is going on.

If I roll the dice `dice.roll();` in my JS file there is no error. It is only erroring with the addEventListener when I click on the button from Chrome.

This is the error I am getting:

Uncaught TypeError: this.changeRoundScore is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.roll (app.js:35)

EDIT: I just changed the `start` function to the following and it worked...can someone explain why?

```
let start = function() {
    console.log(playerOne);
    console.log(playerTwo);
    console.log(dice);

    document.querySelector('.btn-roll').addEventListener('click', function() {
        dice.roll();
        });
}
```

Original code:

```
class Player {
    constructor(active) {
        this.score = 0;
        this.roundScore = [];
        this.active = active;
    }
    changeActive(active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
    addRoundScore(score) {
        this.roundScore.push(score);
    }
}

class Dice {
    constructor(playerOne, playerTwo) {
        document.querySelector('.dice').style.display = 'none';
        this.playerOne = playerOne;
        this.playerTwo = playerTwo;
    }
    roll() {
        let roll = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) + 1;
    //  document.querySelector('.dice').style.display = 'visible';
        this.changeRoundScore(roll);
    }
    changeRoundScore(score) {
        document.querySelector('#current-' + activePlayer).textContent = score;
        document.querySelector('.dice').src = 'dice-' + score + '.png';

        if (activePlayer === 0) {
            playerOne.addRoundScore(score);
        } else if (activePlayer === 1) {
            playerTwo.addRoundScore(score);
        }
    }
}

let activePlayer = 0;

let playerOne = new Player(1);
let playerTwo = new Player(0);
let dice = new Dice(playerOne, playerTwo);

let start = function() {
    console.log(playerOne);
    console.log(playerTwo);
    console.log(dice);

    document.querySelector('.btn-roll').addEventListener('click', dice.roll);
}

start();
```